Scrapy scraping web page giving me blank value for one value
I am trying to scrape this web page with scrapy and I can get all the data I am needing besides the distance. The link https://www.thedogs.com.au/racing/albion-park/2024-05-30/10/tab-flying-amy-classic-h?trial=false
The distance is 520m. How do I get it to scrape this value? Please see the bold code below.
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//td[@class='meetings-venues__race-time']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = {}

    hxs = Selector(response)
    divs = hxs.xpath('//tr[@class="accordion__anchor race-runner"]')   
            
           # titles = [hxs.select('//tr[@class="index class_tr group-6487"] | //tr[@class="index class_tr group-6488"] | //tr[@class="index class_tr group-6489"]')]

    for div in divs:
        item = {
            'grade' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__grade']/text()").extract(),
            'greyhound' : div.xpath('./td[3]/div[1]/a/text()').extract(),
            'position' : div.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract(),
            'trainer' : div.xpath(".//div[@class='race-runners__name__trainer']/a/text()").extract(),
            'weight' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__weight']/text()").extract(),
            'first_sec' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__sectional']/text()").extract_first(),
            'second_sec' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__sectional'][2]/text()").extract(),
            'time' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__time']/text()").extract(),
            'margin' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__margin']/text()").extract(),
            ***'distance' : div.xpath(".//div[@class='race-header__info__grade']/a/text()").extract(),***
            'starting_price' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__starting-price']/text()").extract(),
            'date' : response.url.split('/')[-3],
            'track' : response.url.split('/')[-4],
            'rug' : div.xpath('.//td[@class="table__cell--tight race-runners__box"]/sprite-svg/@name').get()
            #'rug' : div.xpath('//td[@class="table__cell--tight race-runners__box"]/sprite-svg/@name').extract()
            }

        yield item


I see <div class="race-header__info__grade">OPEN 520m</div> in the DOM - so what a element are you trying to match in there ...?

I am trying to get the "520m" specifically. However will  scrape "OPEN 520m" if its easier.  At the moment it is giving me nothing.

"At the moment it is giving me nothing." - because you are trying to match a link inside that div. But there is no link, it contains only text.

I see. I want the text though. How do I change it to give me the text? All the other values work fine which are text so I am slightly confused why this one isn't working.

It's not working, because the /a you are looking for with that XPath expression, doesn't actually exist.

Oh I see. Because its coming from a different location to all the different values. It is not inside of divs = hxs.xpath('//tr[@class="accordion__anchor race-runner"]'). Could I change this line so I can scrape all the data together?

It would probably make more sense to get that value once, before you loop over those table rows.

That makes sense. So I basically just copy paste everything from "def_parse....." onwards and just change it to only get that one value and fix the hxs.xpath line.

I can't work it out at all unfortunately. What should the hxs xpath be to get the distance value?

Grab the distance outside of the loop. I'm using CSS but you can equally use XPath.
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "thedogs"

    start_urls = ["https://www.thedogs.com.au/racing/albion-park/2024-05-30/10/tab-flying-amy-classic-h?trial=false"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    async def parse(self, response):
        # Get distance once outside of loop.
        distance = response.css(".race-header__info__grade::text").get()

        divs = response.xpath('//tr[@class="accordion__anchor race-runner"]')   

        for div in divs:
            yield {
                'distance' : distance,
                'grade' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__grade']/text()").extract(),
                'greyhound' : div.xpath('./td[3]/div[1]/a/text()').extract(),
                'position' : div.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract(),
                'trainer' : div.xpath(".//div[@class='race-runners__name__trainer']/a/text()").extract(),
                'weight' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__weight']/text()").extract(),
                'first_sec' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__sectional']/text()").extract_first(),
                'second_sec' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__sectional'][2]/text()").extract(),
                'time' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__time']/text()").extract(),
                'margin' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__margin']/text()").extract(),
                'starting_price' : div.xpath(".//td[@class='race-runners__starting-price']/text()").extract(),
                'date' : response.url.split('/')[-3],
                'track' : response.url.split('/')[-4],
                'rug' : div.xpath('.//td[@class="table__cell--tight race-runners__box"]/sprite-svg/@name').get()
            }

Output:
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['5'], 'greyhound': ['Pronouns'], 'position': ['1st'], 'trainer': ['T: Tony Brett'], 'weight': ['26.60'], 'first_sec': '5.54', 'second_sec': ['17.09'], 'time': ['29.77'], 'margin': [], 'starting_price': ['$5.50'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_1'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['4'], 'greyhound': ['Cindy Keeping'], 'position': ['2nd'], 'trainer': ['T: Charmaine Roberts'], 'weight': ['28.90'], 'first_sec': '5.58', 'second_sec': ['17.27'], 'time': ['30.05'], 'margin': ['4.00'], 'starting_price': ['$8.50'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_8'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['5'], 'greyhound': ['Excavation'], 'position': ['3rd'], 'trainer': ['T: Jason Thompson'], 'weight': ['28.70'], 'first_sec': '5.56', 'second_sec': ['17.49'], 'time': ['30.21'], 'margin': ['6.25'], 'starting_price': ['$11.00'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_4'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['5'], 'greyhound': ['Which Trap'], 'position': ['4th'], 'trainer': ['T: John Dart'], 'weight': ['32.30'], 'first_sec': '5.67', 'second_sec': ['17.59'], 'time': ['30.32'], 'margin': ['7.75'], 'starting_price': ['$101.00'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_6'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['5'], 'greyhound': ['Mackenna'], 'position': ['5th'], 'trainer': ['T: Michelle Sultana'], 'weight': ['28.20'], 'first_sec': '5.54', 'second_sec': ['17.71'], 'time': ['30.52'], 'margin': ['10.50'], 'starting_price': ['$2.10'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_7'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['4'], 'greyhound': ['Super Scrub'], 'position': ['6th'], 'trainer': ['T: Travis Elson'], 'weight': ['32.80'], 'first_sec': '5.57', 'second_sec': ['17.31'], 'time': ['30.57'], 'margin': ['11.50'], 'starting_price': ['$8.00'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_2'}
{'distance': 'OPEN 520m', 'grade': ['4'], 'greyhound': ["History's Coming"], 'position': ['7th'], 'trainer': ['T: Tomas Rees'], 'weight': ['33.60'], 'first_sec': '5.58', 'second_sec': ['17.43'], 'time': ['30.61'], 'margin': ['12.00'], 'starting_price': ['$5.00'], 'date': '2024-05-30', 'track': 'albion-park', 'rug': 'rug_3'}


This worked! Thank you so much. Very simple solution.

Glad that it helped!
